# How to update big query data according to mapping file?

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a mapping file which is stored in Gcs and a big query table.

df_mapping:

```
             Id     Values
             1      XZUP
             2      SJXC
             3      PALD
             4      QLOM
             5      DKCM
```

BQ_Table:

```
Id  Country  Market  Sales  Values
1   Canada   Hsp     2503   XZUP
2   Germany  Noe     2459   SJXC
3   Algeria  Zoe     4635   PALD
4   Brazil   Foe     6354   QLOM
5   Canada   Cmm     2588   XZUP
```

But the mapping files changes everytime, i am looking for a solution if the mapping file changes my BQ table value should also update as per mapping file.

what i did: `Everytime mapping file changes, i am triggering a function where i am reading bq table except "value" column & reading updated mapping file --> left join on Id column to get updated "values" --> Deleting my old bq table --> Inserting the new data.`

```
query =  """
            SELECT
            Id,
            Country,
            Sales,
            Value
            FROM `project.dataset.tbl` 
            
        """

            bqclient = bigquery.Client()
            df = (
                bqclient.query(query)
                .result()
                .to_dataframe(create_bqstorage_client=True)
                )

df_mapping = pd.read_csv("gs://path/mapping.csv")
df_final = pd.merge(df, df_mapping, on='Id', how='left')
-- Not sure of Deleting and Inserting data safely
```

I am not sure, deleting my old table and inserting new table is a right way to do for this problem.

Problems I see:

```
          1. After deleting my old table, error can come while inserting new data.
          2. Data is quite large to process ~1million.
          3. Not Scalable solution.
          4. Can loss Data.
```

Is there any other way to do it, something like within BQ Table it refers my mapping file or any other solution to this task would be great.

Comment: When you say 'my mapping file changes every time' what is the frequency of change? Also, pd.merge() wont delete the table.? What are you trying to refer when you say "deleting old table"?

Comment: @Mr.Batra frequency would be every qtr, it will not change for all the Id's in mapping file, but it can change for some Id's, so i need to change those Values in BQ table as the values are in mapping file for those particular Id's. So how can i replace those id values in the bq table?  I used to read data from bq table and then i do left join with updated mapping file , which will give the updated values in "value" column.. then i used to delete old data from table inorder to insert new data as per updated mapping file

Answer (score 0):

You could store your mapping referential somewhere (in GCS in CVS format, in Google Sheet for easy manual update, in Cloud SQL database maybe), and then create a view that join your data and the mapping.

Like that, you always have a up to date date, you don't need to store the result and to manage it (update/delete/re-create)

Answer (score 0):

Let's give this a try -

- Create a scheduled UPDATE query ('on demand') in BigQuery. Herein you can have GCS mapping file as first bq table (external table) and your `BQ_Table` as another bq table. Simply write an update query to update `Values` field in `BQ_Table` per mapping file.
- Create a Cloud Function to run above scheduled query as soon mapping data in GCS is updated.